# JGRASP won't run C program after successful compile and link

Tags: jgrasp

Using JGRASP for c++ program.   The program compiles and links with no errors.  When I try to run I get "wedge2 error: could not run ("c:\mplot\mplot.exe"). 
The .exe file exists in that directory !   Anyone understand this error?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to run it from Windows Explorer or from the command prompt?